# How to horizontally align a ul element to center

Tags: html, css, alignment, html-lists

I'm not able to align a menu, contained within a `ul`, to the horizontal center of its container. how to do that?

See a [live demo of the menu on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/krishnathota/tU8R5/).

```html
<li><a href="aboutus.php">AboutUs</a>
    <ul class="sub">
        <li><a href="aboutsquare.php">About Square Innovations</a></li>
        <li><a href="ourvision.php">Our Vision</a></li>
        <li><a href="ourmission.php">Our Mission</a></li>
        <li><a href="trainerprofiles.php">Trainer Profiles</a></li>
        <li><a href="funclass.php">Fun In Our ClassRooms</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can address the `ul` element as an inline-level element within the page flow, while retaining its block-level characteristics (using the `inline-block` display value) — after applying this, it can be simply aligned within its container like any inline-level element, using `text-align`.

To implement this, add the following rules:

```css
#container {
    text-align: center;
}
ul {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Here's the **[updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tU8R5/4/)**.

#### Reference

- [`display` on Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/display)

---

<del>***Disclaimer:** Support for `inline-block` is somewhat limited*</del> nope! it's actually very wide by now, see the [compatibility table on caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=inline-block).

Answer (score 4):

There is a very neath, fully cross-browser and dynamic 'trick' to achieve this, as long as the menu stays on one line. It is very well explained here: http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/beautiful-css-centered-menus-no-hacks-full-cross-browser-support

The inline-block often suggested for this problem is not very well supported in legacy browsers in my experience. To be honest, I never use it. I always go for the clever method that Matthew James Taylor describes.

**Edit:**
As requested I will briefly describe the technique.
Your html should look like a normal list of links, with an extra wrapping div around it. Something like this:

```
<div class="menu-wrapper">
  <ul>
    <li><a ...>link</a></li>
    <li><a ...>link</a></li>
    <li><a ...>link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Now the rest is css work. The steps are as follows:

- Float the wrapper to the left and give it a width of 100% to make it take up the full viewport width
- Float both the `ul` and the `li` to the left and don't give them any width to make them adjust to their content.
- Give the `ul` a `position: relative` of `left: 50%`. This will make it's left edge move to the center of it's parent, and this means the center of the viewport.
- Finally you should give your `li` a `position: relative` of `left: -50%`. This will make them move past the left edge of the parent `ul` and makes the center of the list of `li`'s line up with the left edge of the parent `ul`. Since we made that edge the center of our viewport in the previous step, the menu is now effectively centered.

As I said before, *all credits to Matthew James Taylor*, and definitly check out [his thorough explanation](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/beautiful-css-centered-menus-no-hacks-full-cross-browser-support). The drawings he made make it much easier to understand.

**edit**
As requested I set up a little fiddle to demonstrate the technique: 
http://jsfiddle.net/fDmCQ/

Comment: you are, of course, correct. (older) IE will have trouble rendering `inline-block` elements. this is a *great* article, please describe the underlying logic or encompass the highlights within your answer to make it self contained.

Comment: @Eliran glad you like it. I took your suggestion and improved my answer. And I look forward to day we do no longer have to support old IE versions (or no IE at all if it where up to me)! ;-)

Comment: Can you please provide me a fiddle formy example ??

Comment: @krishna I tried to make a fiddle on my iPad (which I do not recommend) and put the link in my answer. Feel free to ask if you want any further explanation!

Answer (score 1):

Change the margin on the `<ul>` to `0 auto` and give it a width (~575px or larger).

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/tU8R5/2/)**

```
 ul {
     font-family: Arial, Verdana;
     font-size: 14px;
     margin: 0 auto;
     padding: 0;
     width:600px;
     list-style: none;
     text-align: center;
 }
```

Comment: this requires the addition of an explicit width to the `ul` element, making it rigid. what if you add more list items?

Comment: What's with the down vote? Is this answer somehow not useful or incorrect?