# Centered Menu w/ CSS

Tags: html, css, center

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2GG7Y/)

I need to center my fixed header nav that is using an unordered list. The middle list item is left empty as I am putting a background image there in its place.

Right now it "looks" centered though if you rubberband the browser window you can see that it is not. I can achieve *almost* middle by reducing the width from 960px to ~780px but I don't want to have to do that.

I'm sure I'm overlooking something simple here. Thanks!

**HTML:**

```
<header>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a class="active" href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
            <li class="logo"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}


body{
    background-color: #ebebeb;
}

nav {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
}

li{
    display: inline-block;
    height: 120px;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 120px;
    margin-right: 30px;
}

.logo {
    height: 130px;
    width: 164px;
    background:url(http://samaradionne.com/img/typeBlack.png) no-repeat;
}

section.stretch{
    float: left;
    height: 1500px;
    width: 100%;
}

header{
    width: 100%;
    background: #fff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 10;
    text-align: center;
}

header a{
    color: #969696;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family:  sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Comment: Check out this thread/answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8228669/1375372

Comment: I was able to get the header to center by adding "display: inline-block;" to the ul element.

Comment: and another thread (there must be hundreds) http://stackoverflow.com/a/14511370/1340674

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could also use an `inline-table`

```
ul {
  display:inline-table;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2GG7Y/13/

You could take the CSS table a step further with

```
li {
  display:table-cell;
}
```

Though, these elements will work in most browsers, you may want to cross test for fallbacks.

Comment: I like that you're working with tables & cells, which I think would allow me to use vertical-align also would it not? Ideally I'd like to remove the line-height to the li so that it centers vertically with the logo.

Comment: If you wanted to do that you could just nix the `ul` display style and go with `display:inline-block` on your `li` style. I would move the image outside of the `ul` as an actual `img` myself, just to be on the safe side. If (for some awful reason CSS was disabled or not loading), your logo would still show. Plus it's readable content for SEO. `alt` text for the win.

Comment: Check out this fiddle. It also uses responsive widths so you're not stuck with a 960px block of content. http://jsfiddle.net/2GG7Y/16/

Answer (score 3):

Add `display: inline-block;` to the `ul` and it will properly center

**Working fiddle:**

http://jsfiddle.net/2GG7Y/12/

Comment: FYI - I did not see the above comments when I answered, they were posted at the same time I suppose

Answer (score 1):

set `ul` to `display:inline-block;`

```
ul{
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/2GG7Y/10/