# How to center a text in circle bullets?

Tags: css

I have some CSS problem. On the website http://astrazlata.rs/ on the accordion section "Finansijski izveštaji", how can I make text inside that section center on the page, so that is not align to the left? I tried few ways with text-align:center or margin: 0 auto, but it want works.

Also I on the accordion I have some problem with:

```
ul {
     list-style: circle;
}
```

When I leave it like that, page push that circle bullets little bit outside the section (it looks ugly and unclean), but it nicely displays text.

Other scenario is when add:

```
ul {
    list-style: circle inside;    
 }
```

circle bulltets are displayed perfectly in the line with the section but text acts little bit funky like this - https://www.dropbox.com/s/pb3kxmfjod3084d/bullets%28text%29.png?dl=0 
Is there any way to solve that problem, so that circle bullets are in line with section, but without the funky looking text?

Comment: Someone will tell you to include the code in the question as well, since it is possible that at some point your external site will not be available. So, please include the code in the question.

Comment: Anyway, this has most likely been asked and answered. E.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10428720/how-to-keep-indent-for-second-line-in-ordered-lists-via-css

Comment: You should place text-align:center on parent element, in this case, content-item-3, but not sure that it will give you desired look...

Comment: @Roope thank you for link. Yes, I have found solution in that question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10428720/how-to-keep-indent-for-second-line-in-ordered-lists-via-css

Answer (score 1):

For the first part of your question.

https://jsfiddle.net/wieslaw/y26k6amu/.

Answer to your question is also in https://stackoverflow.com/a/14510696/1643235.

```
.container { 
  text-align: center;
}

ul { 
  display: inline-block; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much that is the solution for one of mine accordion problems.

Answer (score 0):

add following code into your style.css file:

```
.accordion-content ul {
position: relative;
left: 50%;
}
```

you can adjust 50%; value to whatever you like.